# How would I go about aligning x-axis labels with the tick marks they correspond to in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm using the following code to generate an x axis, tick marks, and tick labels in an SVG element, and I can't really figure out the best way to center align the tick labels with the tick marks, given the width of the tick labels is not fixed.

```
<svg viewBox='0 0 1000 300'>
  <!-- main x-axis line -->
  <line x1='0' y1='225' x2='950' y2='225' />

  <!-- tick marks and labels -->
  <line x1='95' y1='215' x2='95' y2='235' />
  <text x='95' y='250'>8PM</text>

  <line x1='190' y1='215' x2='190' y2='235' />
  <text x='190' y='250'>10PM</text>

  ...
</svg>
```

Ultimately, I'm not quite sure how to calculate the width of the text so I can adjust the `x` coordinate appropriately. Is there any way of doing this with native JavaScript (i.e. no jQuery)? I only ask because I hate to import jQuery just for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that what you want is the text-anchor attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor